# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы в html файле любая гиперссылка открывалась в новой вкладке, не задавая target в каждом теге?

Tags: html

Я создал простой HTML документ и хочу, как мне установить атрибут `target` тега `<a>` по умолчанию со значением `_blank`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="https://youtube.com">YT(self)</a>
    <br>
    <a href="https://github.com" target="_blank">github(blank)</a>
    <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<head>
  <base target="_blank">
</head>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Выучил новое.